# NodeJS send array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a trouble with NodeJS. I have to send an array of array that is structured like this:

```
[
   "val1":["one","two","three"],
   "val2":["four","five","six"],
   "val3":["seven","eight","nine"]
]
```

So, when I try to do res.send, in my browser (Chrome) I show only `[]`.

How can I send my array?

Comment: That's not a valid JavaScript structure. You can't JSON-encode it as it throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `send` function expects a JavaScript object, which can be marshalled as a valid JSON string. In your case, you have a JavaScript array, with three properties. But JSON arrays support only integer keys (called indices).

So, you might want to change the array to a JavaScript object, like this

```
res.send({
  "val1": ["one", "two", "three"],
  "val2": ["four", "five", "six"],
  "val3": ["seven", "eight", "nine"]
});
```